# PostgreSql PgAdmin cant connect to a database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, pgadmin

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server requested SCRAM-based authentication, but no password was provided.

```
`application.yml:
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jwt_security
    username: postgres
    password: Zygimantas1
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
    database: postgresql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`
```

```
`User.java class:
package com.zygimantas.security.user;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data                       //Generates getters and setters
@Builder                    //Help us build our object
@NoArgsConstructor          //Needed for @builder to work
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "_user")

public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String email;
    private String password;
}`
```

I have made the server on pdagmin and database. I tried to make a passwordless server but It wont let me create one or even a server with any other password other then the one above in the yml file. I tried so many things but I cant get this database to connect

[PGadmin ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2szY.png)
[ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScGQy.png)

Tried following previous "but no password was provided." forums and everything. Tried making new databases etc.

Comment: "I tried to make a passwordless server but It wont let me create one"  What did you do?  You showed the attempt to make it with a password.  Then you tried something else, but didn't show it.

Comment: It literally just says not password provided: 
[link] (https://gyazo.com/e885f137ce9400c898516819a4eb7544)

Comment: You tried to *register* a server into pgadmin without using a password for it.  That is not the same thing as trying to create a server which doesn't need a password.  Obviously if the server demands a password, then you need to supply that password.

Comment: Yes okay, but why it is set to one certain password it's just weird. But I know the password. But it just won't let me connect to the database it says no password provided. I found a workaround. I installed inteliJ and used that, it has built in postgresql feature and I connected to the same database. so I don't know theb